# jq unable to process sfdx json output

Tags: salesforcedx, jq

I am trying to parse json output from sfdx commands. Somehow jq throws the below exception. Unable to figure out.

I am trying this in bash shell in windows 10 environment.

$ `sfdx force:schema:sobject:describe -s Account -u wmsandbox --json | ./jq -r '.result.fields[] | .label, .name'`

**parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2
Error: EOF: end of file, write**
    at Object.info (c:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/cli-ux/lib/index.js:50:24)
    at Object.styledJSON (c:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/cli-ux/lib/styled/json.js:15:17)
    at UX.logJson (c:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@salesforce/command/lib/ux.js:95:18)
    at SchemaSobjectDescribeCommand.finally (c:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@salesforce/command/lib/sfdxCommand.js:305:25)
    at SchemaSobjectDescribeCommand._run (c:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@salesforce/command/lib/sfdxCommand.js:98:31)

$ `sfdx force:schema:sobject:describe -s Account -u wmsandbox --json > out.json`

$ `cat out.json | ./jq -r '.result.fields[] | .label, .name'`

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2

$ `head out.json`

{
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "actionOverrides": [
      {
        "formFactor": "LARGE",
        "isAvailableInTouch": false,
        "name": "View",
        "pageId": "0M01D000000D1IBSA0",
        "url": null

$

Comment: Please use the `{}` and `"` tools in the editor to format your question. Your latest edit wiped out the formatting changes I made.